# Create Dict from Text File + Python:TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

Trying to create a dict from this piece of text:

```
game_name: Adventure 1
game_goal: Find the magic helmet and bring it to Hans.
game_goalloc: 8
game_goalobj: helmet
game_start: 4
game_xsize: 3
game_ysize: 3
```

Read in as "config.txt", keep getting a Type Error: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Can't for the life of me figure out why as doing the exact same operation elsewhere in my code... HELLLP

```
with open('config.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if "game_" in line:
        game = line.split('_')[-1]
        k = game.split(':')[0]
        v = game.split(':')[-1]
        print(k)
        print(v)
        game[k] = {}
        game[k] = v
```

Comment: `k = game.split(':')[0]`, its clear that game is a string, As strings are immutable, this is invalid `game[k] = {}` or `game[k] = v`

Comment: Yeah... I figured it out. I was using game as the name of the dictionary as well as a variable in the loop. Duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created a empty dictionary   `game_dict = {}` and updated it.

```
 with open('game1.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    game_dict = {}
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
    
        if "game_" in line:
            game = line.split('_')[-1]
    
            k = game.split(':')[0]
            game_dict[k] = ""
            v = game.split(':')[-1]
            game_dict[k] = v
    
    
    print(game_dict)
```

*Output*

```
{'name': ' Adventure 1', 'goal': ' Find the magic helmet and bring it to Hans.', 'goalloc': ' 8', 'goalobj': ' helmet', 'start': ' 4', 'xsize': ' 3', 'ysize': ' 3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    game = line.split('_')[-1]
    k = game.split(':')[0]
    v = game.split(':')[-1]
    print(k)
    print(v)
    game[k] = {}
    game[k] = v
```

in the last two lines of codes, you are trying to assign the "game", a str object, with empty {} and then v. this results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = """
game_name: Adventure 1
game_goal: Find the magic helmet and bring it to Hans.
game_goalloc: 8
game_goalobj: helmet
game_start: 4
game_xsize: 3
game_ysize: 3
""".strip().splitlines()

game_dict = {}

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if "game_" in line:
        game = line.split('_')[-1]
        k = game.split(':')[0].strip()
        v = game.split(':')[-1].strip()
        print(k)
        print(v)
        game_dict[k] = {}
        game_dict[k] = v

print(game_dict)
```

Maybe this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Yes - I figured that out just after posting.

I was initializing the dict variable as game and then using the same var within the loop. Silly mistake...

Here is my fixed code:

```
game = {}
map = {}

#need to update location variable here when a move is made
character = {'inventory': [], 'location': 1}

with open('game1.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if "game_" in line:
        split = line.split('_')[-1]

        k,v = split.split(':')
        game[k] = v
```